# What is the best way to demonstrate spoofing?

Tags: wireless, spoofing, arp-spoofing

I use this tutorial to spoof with Kali Linux on VirtualBox: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ssl-stripping-and-arp-spoofing-in-kali-linux/

However got some errors

```
ip route:
```

Route information

```
10.1.80.121 dev calie682995647a scope link 
10.1.80.122 dev calie71c7941af4 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.97 metric 600 
192.168.49.0/24 dev br-a6bc27b2d861 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.49.1 
192.168.56.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.1
```

Command

```
arpspoof -i wlp1s0 -t  192.168.43.0  -r  192.168.43.97
```

Got

```
arpspoof: couldn't arp for spoof host 192.168.43.97
```

What is the best way/tutorial to demo spoofing for a man-in-the-middle attack for beginners?

I have only physical PC, VirtualBox with linux, docker, local website accessible from VirtualBox machine with linux, mobile internet shared as hotspot.

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue. So, do you want the "best way to demonstrate spoofing" or do you want this error fixed?